# Unable to automate video/object tag for video div using Selenium Web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate web application which has video div as its one of our scenarios. But I am not getting inner web elements to find locators to perform some actions. Wherein you can find screenshot for your reference as its Object tag which has no child Web elements present.
Let me know if we can automate such scenarios in case of using Selenium web driver or any other third-party libraries.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code trial and stack error? Also please [Edit] your question and update with text based html.

Comment: add more details otherwise we cannot help